# Java Array element mentioned in MySQL insertion query not getting inserted into table .Instead an error is being thrown

Tags: java, mysql, xampp

I am taking values from the users such as : name , address, phone number, city , destination , date

Each of these values is stored in their respective array . Before moving into the next iteration of the array , I want to insert the array element into a MYSQL table 
. I am using JDBC for this . However I am being shown the error that the SQL query is not correct :

This is my SQL query:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO `registration`(`phone`, `name`, `address`, `city`, `destination`, `date`) VALUES (100,name[i],address[i],city[i],destination[i],date[i])";
```

This is the relevant code part where I am doing SQL query

```
 case 1: {
                        System.out.println("Enter your Phone number:");
                        phone[i] = sc.nextInt();
                        sc.nextLine();

                        System.out.println("Enter your name:");
                        name[i] = sc.nextLine();


                        System.out.println("Enter your address:");
                        address[i] = sc.nextLine();

                        System.out.println("Enter your Pick up city:");
                        city[i] = sc.nextLine();


                        System.out.println("Enter your Destination:");
                        destination[i] = sc.nextLine();


                        System.out.println("Enter your Date:");
                        date[i] = sc.nextLine();
                        ++i;
                        Connection conn = null;
                        Statement stmt = null;
                        try{
                            //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
                            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                            //STEP 3: Open a connection
                            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
                            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
                            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

                            //STEP 4: Execute a query
                            System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");
                            stmt = conn.createStatement();
                            String sql = "INSERT INTO `registration`(`phone`, `name`, `address`, `city`, `destination`, `date`) VALUES (100,name[i],address[i],city[i],destination[i],date[i])";
                            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

                        }catch(SQLException se){
                            //Handle errors for JDBC
                            se.printStackTrace();
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            //Handle errors for Class.forName
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }finally{
                            //finally block used to close resources
                            try{
                                if(stmt!=null)
                                    conn.close();
                            }catch(SQLException se){
                            }// do nothing
                            try{
                                if(conn!=null)
                                    conn.close();
                            }catch(SQLException se){
                                se.printStackTrace();
                            }//end finally try
                        }//end try
                        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                        break;
                    }
```

This is the error I am being shown :

This is my SQL query from the above code

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[i],address[i],city[i],destination[i],date[i])' at line 1
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1540)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2595)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1468)
        at Airplane.main(Airplane.java:74)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So much wrong. 1) Don't put the table name and column names in quotes. 2) Lookup how to add parameters in a prepared statement.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'd better use `PreparedStatement` to achieve some degree of type safety and protection from SQL injection. Also `PreparedStatement` allows to insert several rows in batch mode which improves performance.

You need to create `PreparedStatement` object only once outside of your loop.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `registration`(`phone`, `name`, `address`, `city`, `destination`, `date`) VALUES (100,?,?,?,?,?)");
stmt.setString(1, name[i]);
stmt.setString(2, address[i]);
stmt.setString(3, city[i]);
stmt.setString(4, destination[i]);
stmt.setString(5, date[i]);
```